# change height of query result rows - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to increase the row height of the rows in the query results. I like big fonts and at some point the font becomes too big for the row.

Example: Everything is fine with font size 19:
[image]

But with font size 22, which is what I like, the underscore disappears: 
[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Or other ideas to have the results (and the code, as this uses the same font size setting) in a big font? Searching google and the preferences of Oracle SQL Developer didn't help.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Anyway, did you consider investing into new spectacles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can offer you is to leave the grid and print to the script output area. There's no restriction of line width height there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, an honor to get a response right from the source ^^ Unfortunately that won't do the trick for my daily work. But I know now that it's not possible via the grid. Maybe a feature you could put on the bottom of your backlog ^^